# IP address parsing in python

Tags: python, mysql, regex, python-3.x

Below string expression contains two IP numbers at the end of it.

I need to extract them and duplicate the entire string. So, that both IP addresses are included in separate strings each of which is identical, except the IP that they contain.

What would be the most resource efficient way to do this in python involving regular expressions?

P.S.: The IP address in below text might not be real IPs but in the problem you can assume that there will be valid IP addresses. You can assume there will be a few thousands of such insert statements where IP addresses have to be splitted.

```
 INSERT INTO DemandTable 
 (
      [FullName], [ServerName],
      [ServerType], [Ram],
      [Processor], [Core],
      [DataDiscCapacity], [BootDiscCapacity],
      [OperatingSystem], [SystemDate], 
      [IP]
 )
 VALUES 
 (
      'Lucky Look', 'FILE',
      'APPLICATION', '4',
      '2, '2',
      '859.9951171875', '39.482421875',
      'Windows Server', 'Wednesday, March 5, 2014 8:37:48 AM EET',
      '179.13.9.111, 179.17.0.10'
)
```

SO the OUTPUT should be:

```
 INSERT INTO DemandTable 
 (
     [FullName], [ServerName],
     [ServerType], [Ram],
     [Processor], [Core],
     [DataDiscCapacity], [BootDiscCapacity],
     [OperatingSystem],[SystemDate], 
     [IP]
 )
 VALUES 
 (
     'Lucky Look','FILE',
     'APPLICATION','4',
     '2,'2',
     '859.9951171875','39.482421875',
     'Windows Server','Wednesday, March 5, 2014 8:37:48 AM EET',
     '179.13.9.111'
 )


 INSERT INTO DemandTable 
 (
     [FullName], [ServerName],
     [ServerType], [Ram],
     [Processor], [Core],
     [DataDiscCapacity], [BootDiscCapacity],
     [OperatingSystem], [SystemDate], 
     [IP]
 )
 VALUES 
 (
     'Lucky Look','FILE',
     'APPLICATION','4',
     '2,'2',
     '859.9951171875','39.482421875',
     'Windows Server','Wednesday, March 5, 2014 8:37:48 AM EET',
     '179.17.0.10'
 )
```

Comment: \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} can easily get the ip adresses

Comment: @LanceToth - that only works for the old, exhausted, IPv4.

Comment: @RickJames I see your point, but the example contains no IPv6 adresses

Comment: @RickJames Does this work for IPv6? `([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:?|:){1,8}`

Comment: @LanceToth - It may be close.  I suspect this is valid but fails:  `::1b2c`.  And it would be tricky to say that only one `::` is allowed.  (But then the IPv4 regexp does not prevent numbers bigger than 255.)